# The name "DoublerConvert" does not exist in Namespace "clr-...."

Tags: wpf, vb.net, converters, ivalueconverter

I realise that there are other questions with the same title, however I have tried all of those solutions to no avail. I am trying to use a converter that I have made. My other converter works fine, and this new one is a copy paste of the previous one, with the name changed, and the return value changed.

XAML

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ARC"
    <local:DoublerConvert x:Key="DoubleConverter"/> 'Doesn't work
    <local:ValueConverter x:Key="NegativeConverter"/> 'Works fine
```

CODE

```
Public Class ValueConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Function ProvideValue(serviceProvider As System.IServiceProvider) As Object
        Return Me
    End Function

    Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        Dim OldWidth As Integer = value
        OldWidth = -OldWidth
        Return OldWidth
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function
End Class

Public Class DoublerConvert
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Function ProvideValue(serviceProvider As System.IServiceProvider) As Object
        Return Me
    End Function

    Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        Dim OldWidth As Integer = value
        Return 2 * OldWidth
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Have you made sure to rebuild the assembly containing the converter code?

Comment: Yes I have. I tried Cleaning, Rebuilding as well as Save All>Exit>Start VS Again>Clean>Rebuild

Comment: Are these two classes contained in the same code file? Double check that both have the same namespace definitions. It's a common problem with things like Converters where they get moved around but their namespace isn't updated, then when you add a new one in the new location, the namespace differs from the original even though they live in the same folder.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You try to kill XDesProc.exe and reload your xaml.

Comment: What is XDesProc.exe? Where does it fit into all this? Even the littlest bit of context would make this a much more useful answer.

Comment: @mickeyf you can kill it through Windows Task Manager -> Processes -> XDesProc.exe (right click -> End process)

Comment: Just clearing solution and rebuilding solved the issue on VS2019

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in c#. I've read so much information about this problem. So what did i do to fix it? I ran clean project and then built project. VS showed me the error list and i fixed each error! each! after that my solution built successfully! hope it will work for you!